# How to conditionally run PHP code only when query returns results?

Tags: php

I hope someone can help me with the best way to structure this code.

I run an oil club as a volunteer and if there are no quotes for a specific oil type, then the page fails due to empty variables being used in queries further down the code.

Ideally I would like to default to `$win_supplier_red_id = 0` if the query returns no results, but I'm not sure the best way to catch it and where is the best place in the code.

```
$sql2a= "Select Quote_id from tbl_quote where (select min(quote_price) as best_red from tbl_quote where fuel_type_id =2 AND timestamp > date_sub( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY ) AND quote_price > 10) = quote_price AND timestamp > date_sub( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY ) Order by timestamp Limit 1";
$stmt2a = $db->prepare($sql2a);
$stmt2a->execute();
$res2a = $stmt2a->fetchObject();
$best_red_quote = $res2a->Quote_id;
$sql2= "SELECT qt.quote_id, ft.fuel_type_id, ft.fuel_name, st.supplier_id, st.company_name as company_name, st.email, qt.supplier_id, qt.timestamp, qt.fuel_type_id, min( qt.quote_price ) AS best_red
FROM tbl_quote qt
INNER JOIN `tbl_suppliers` st ON qt.supplier_id = st.supplier_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_fuel-type` ft ON qt.fuel_type_id = ft.fuel_type_id
WHERE qt.Quote_id = $best_red_quote
Order by timestamp";
$stmt2 = $db->prepare($sql2);
$stmt2->execute();
$res2 = $stmt2->fetchObject();
$best_red = $res2->best_red;
$winning_supplier_red = $res2->company_name;
$win_supplier_red_id = $res2->supplier_id;
```

Comment: If(count(result)>0){do something}else{do something else}

Comment: Please be aware that you should avoid question like "what is the best way to..." on Stack Overflow. Instead you could ask what possible solutions are there and what are pros and cons of each one. Usually there is no ultimate solution to a problem and you have to decide which one suits you most. We know very little about your application and its requirements, therefore it is tricky for us to answer such question.

See Example #2 in this PHP manual page for information about possible solution to your problem: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt2 = $db->prepare($sql2);
$stmt2->execute();
$res2 = $stmt2->fetchObject();

if (is_object($res2)) {
    $best_red = $res2->best_red;
    $winning_supplier_red = $res2->company_name;
    $win_supplier_red_id = isset($res2->supplier_id) ? $res2->supplier_id : 0;
} else {
     $best_red = '';
     $winning_supplier_red = '';
     $win_supplier_red_id = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, would it work the same if I put the the If clause after the first query and put the second query inside the If true section?

Comment: Yes, I think so